# How would gravity affect a flat object with a slightly larger area than Earth's surface area, but lower in mass?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Imagine a flat object slightly wider than the Earth's surface area whose mass is much lower than that of Earth. If it landed on Earth, would the curvature of gravity bend it, or possibly even break it? If not, would it start to overlap itself? If it were subsequently ejected from Earth's orbit, would it resume its original shape or remain curved?

Comment: *wider than the Earth's surface area* What does that mean? An area is not a width.

Comment: It would make a difference whether it was made of steel, Silly Putty, or something else. Different materials bend or break more easily than others.

Comment: @G. Smith What if it were made of wood?

Comment: Perhaps someone will be willing to do that calculation.

Comment: @G. Smith I'm not looking for a calculation so much as a general idea of how the curvature of gravity would affect the shape of a body from space.

Comment: Well I think it is clear that gravity would tend to bend it toward the Earth. How much depends on density, stiffness, thickness, etc.

Comment: @G. Smith I think that answers my question. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.